# TCP Implementation on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, tcp

How can I find the type of TCP running on my Mac OS X? (TCP Reno, Fast TCP, ...)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by type of TCP running. Can you explain what you are looking for?

Comment: how congestion control is implemented in TCP? for example, TCP reno, Fast TCP, ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mac OS X apparently supports SACKs, making Reno obsolete...

```
net.inet.tcp.sack: 1
```

vs

```
net.inet.tcp.newreno: 0
```

(from sysctl net | grep net.inet.tcp)

[More here](http://www.macgeekery.com/tips/configuration/mac_os_x_network_tuning_guide_revisited).

Answer (score -2):

If it is congestion control implementation you need to identify,
<strike>it might be easier to</strike> you can also **look at the TCP packet stream from the machine**.
Here is a StackOverflow question on [how to 'fingerprint' TCP Congestion control algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528733/is-there-an-algorithm-for-fingerprinting-the-tcp-congestion-control-algorithm-use).

Comment: @TheDownVoter, a brief explanation for the down-vote will be highly appreciated.